# Applying Functions to a Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm still learning Python and the basic rules here as well so please correct me if I'm making a faux pas.  One can't grow without proper criticism and coaching.

I'm trying to help my wife with a volunteer schedule for a fund raiser she is conducting.  The day contains 7 hourly events and I have 7 hourly schedules that will have a person working for 4 of the 7 events, for the volunteers to pick from.

What this code does is calculate the number of each schedule I'll need to meet the event volunteer requirements based on the number of volunteers I have available.  I currently do not know the exact number of volunteers she will have available.

```
import random
    # Volunteer Requirements for each of the 7 events
r = [6, 12, 14, 14, 12, 16, 10]
    # Available Schedules where 0 = hour off and 1 = hour working
s = []
s.append([0,1,1,1,1,0,0])
s.append([0,0,1,1,1,1,0])
s.append([0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
s.append([1,1,1,1,0,0,0])
s.append([1,1,0,0,0,1,1])
s.append([1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
s.append([1,0,0,0,1,1,1])

number_of_schedules = len(s)
number_of_vols = 21
number_of_hours = len(s[0])

while True:
    q = [0]*number_of_schedules
    for i in range(number_of_vols):
        q[random.randint(0,len(q)-1)] += 1
    t = [sum([q[j]*s[j][i] for j in range(number_of_schedules)]) for i in range(number_of_hours)]
    if sum([r[i] <= t[i] for i in range(number_of_hours)]) == number_of_hours:
        print '\n'.join(map(str,q))
        print '\n'.join(map(str,s))
        break
```

When I run the code it prints as:

```
3
8
2
1
6
2
0
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

This tells me that in order to meet the requirements I will need 3 people to take the first schedule, 8 to take the second, 2 to take the third, and so on.

What I want to do is build the list 's' as a dict so that I can give a name to each schedule, i.e. 'Schedule A', 'Schedule B', etc.  This way I can call the print function to print each schedule the number of times it is needed.

The preferred end result would look something like this when I call the print function.

```
    Schedule A 
    Schedule A 
    Schedule B 
    Schedule B 
    Schedule B 
    Schedule B 
    Schedule B 
    ........
    Schedule G
```

Then each volunteer can put their name next to an available schedule.

The problem I run into is that regardless of what method I attempt, I cannot get it to work correctly.  I'm hoping to get this done by Friday as my wife wants to send out a volunteer request email this weekend.  Any help/direction anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "regardless of what method I attempt, I cannot get it to work correctly." -- Please include this attempt and describe how it was unsuitable.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Each list in in s is an event? What exactly are you having trouble with?    I'm assuming you want something like, `sDict = {"eventOne": [0,0...0], "eventTwo": [0,0...0],...}` Is that correct?

Comment: If I am reading this right, you are randomly throwing schedules at volunteers until you find a combination that meets all minimum requirements? This seems sub-optimal, and if you don't have enough volunteers it will run forever.

Comment: @16num that is correct.  Yet when I build sDict = {"schedule a": [0,0...], "schedule b": [1,0,1....]} and try to run it I get the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type".

Comment: @HughBothwell Each year we've had to many volunteers and we would just throw schedules at them at random.  This will give them a chance to pick a schedule that allows them to attend an event if they are not needed to work one.  They'll be able to plan in advance knowing when they are needed to work.

Comment: @khelwood I'll have to go back through my notes, but I found a number of solutions here that appeared as though they would work, yet failed each time.  I believe it's due to a lack of understanding on my part and I"m not applying the functions correctly.

Comment: I have to say I found this quite interesting, and I want to applaud your ingenuity. One technical note: The code you posted doesn't generate the output you posted. Surely you meant 22 volunteers, not 21.

Comment: @backofthepackbiped where are you getting the error?  are you saying that `sDict = {"eventOne": [0,1]}` is what's throwing the  error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interest I coded this as a genetic search:

```
import numpy as np
from random import choice, randrange
from string import ascii_uppercase

# volunteer requirements for each of the 7 events
NEEDED = np.array([6, 12, 14, 14, 12, 16, 10], dtype=np.int32)

# available schedules where 0 = hour off and 1 = hour working
SCHEDULES = np.array([
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
], dtype=np.int32)

NAMES = ["Schedule {}".format(ch) for ch in ascii_uppercase[:len(SCHEDULES)]]

def alloc_random(num, schedules):
    """
    Create a random allocation of schedules
    """
    num_schedules = len(schedules)
    alloc = np.zeros(num_schedules, dtype=np.int32)
    for _ in range(num):
        alloc[randrange(num_schedules)] += 1
    return alloc

def alloc_mutate(alloc):
    """
    Randomly replace one schedule with another
    """
    alloc = np.copy(alloc)   # make a new allocation (instead of modifying the parent)
    num_schedules = len(alloc)
    while True:
        from_ = randrange(num_schedules)
        to_ = randrange(num_schedules)
        if from_ != to_ and alloc[from_] > 0:
            alloc[from_] -= 1
            alloc[to_] += 1
            return alloc

def alloc_fitness(alloc):
    """
    Given a schedule allocation,
      return the minimum (volunteers present / needed) of any period
    """
    return np.min(alloc.dot(SCHEDULES) / NEEDED)

def alloc_find_best(num_volunteers, needed, schedules, population=20, children=100, generations=1000):
    """
    Find the best way to assign schedules to volunteers
    """
    # generate starting population
    pop = [alloc_random(num_volunteers, schedules) for _ in range(population)]
    # evolve!
    for gen in range(generations):
        # create evolved children
        ch = [alloc_mutate(choice(pop)) for _ in range(children)]
        # add the parents to the evaluation pool
        ch.extend(pop)
        # sort from most to least fit
        ch.sort(key=alloc_fitness, reverse=True)
        # decimate
        pop = ch[:population]
    # return the best solution found
    return pop[0]

def main():
    for num_volunteers in range(21, 25):
        best = alloc_find_best(num_volunteers, NEEDED, SCHEDULES)
        print("\n{:>2d} volunteers:  fitness = {:0.1f}%".format(num_volunteers, 100. * alloc_fitness(best)))
        for label,val in zip(NAMES, best):
            print("{:>14s}: {:>2d}".format(label, val))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which gives output like

```
21 volunteers:  fitness = 92.9%
    Schedule A:  4
    Schedule B:  7
    Schedule C:  2
    Schedule D:  0
    Schedule E:  6
    Schedule F:  2
    Schedule G:  0

22 volunteers:  fitness = 100.0%
    Schedule A:  3
    Schedule B:  8
    Schedule C:  2
    Schedule D:  1
    Schedule E:  6
    Schedule F:  2
    Schedule G:  0

23 volunteers:  fitness = 100.0%
    Schedule A:  2
    Schedule B:  9
    Schedule C:  2
    Schedule D:  2
    Schedule E:  6
    Schedule F:  2
    Schedule G:  0

24 volunteers:  fitness = 107.1%
    Schedule A:  4
    Schedule B:  9
    Schedule C:  2
    Schedule D:  0
    Schedule E:  7
    Schedule F:  2
    Schedule G:  0
```

There are a couple of points of interest:

- just adding up the needed volunteer slots shows you need a minimum of 84 / 4 == 21 volunteers
- running this a couple of times shows that you need a minimum of 22 volunteers to actually be able to schedule everything, and at least 24 to have a spare in every time slot
- your randomly discovered solution is actually exactly the same as what I got, but my algorithm runs much faster - 0.8s vs an average of 36s (anything from 12s to 86s in my testing).

To get the final result format you want,

```
for name,num,sched in zip(NAMES, best, SCHEDULES):
    for _ in range(num):
        print(name + "  " + str(sched))
```

which gives something like

```
Schedule A  [0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
Schedule A  [0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
Schedule A  [0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule B  [0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
Schedule C  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
Schedule C  [0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
Schedule D  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule E  [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]
Schedule F  [1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
Schedule F  [1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
```

I also did a bit of sensitivity analysis like

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(tuple(alloc_find_best(22, NEEDED, SCHEDULES)) for _ in range(100))
```

which gave

```
{
    (2, 8, 2, 2, 6, 2, 0): 32,
    (3, 8, 2, 1, 6, 2, 0): 39,
    (4, 8, 2, 0, 6, 2, 0): 29
}
```

which says that only 3 solutions were found in 100 trials, that the second solution was found slightly more often, but that all three were roughly as likely. It is interesting to note that the only difference between them is a trade-off between schedules A and D == time slots 1 and 5.

Comment: Thanks!  This does run much quicker than what I had build.  I did have a follow up.  When I run `for name,num,sched in zip(NAMES, best, SCHEDULES):
    for _ in range(num):
        print(name + "  " + str(sched)) ` I get `NameError: name 'best' is not defined `  yet I see that it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Hugh Bothwell's solution is very nice if you need the extra speed or scientific rigor. It kind of answers a question that wasn't asked, though. If you're happy with the way the calculations are working now, and just want to be able to print the schedule *names* rather than (or in addition to) the sequence of zeros and ones, it's much simpler.

You're not going to be able to "multiply" a whole dictionary by a number. There are fancy ways to make a dictionarylike object which will work the way you seem to want, but I think that's overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

It's low-tech and perhaps not elegant-looking, but the simplest thing to do is make another list that just consists of schedule names, in the same order as `s`. A given index in `s` will correspond to the same index in the list of names. (On the off-chance you won't be processing them sequentially, you can look up the index for a given value using `.index()`. For example, `s.index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])` would return 2.)